# How do I display the legend name associated with a series in the HoverTool tooltip in Bokeh?

Tags: python-2.7, plot, bokeh

In the code below I would like to know what to put in the place of the "????" so that the hover tool will show the name of the series (in this example either "series 1" or "series 2")

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips=[("series name","????")]

f = figure(tools=[hover])

f.line([1,2,3],[2,1,5],legend="series 1")
f.line([1,2,3],[1,7,2],legend="series 2")

show(f)
```

I know you can do the following to make this work (see [In Bokeh, how do I add tooltips to a Timeseries chart (hover tool)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496628/in-bokeh-how-do-i-add-tooltips-to-a-timeseries-chart-hover-tool)).  However I am embedding the plots in an HTML file that will have many data points per plot and many plots in the file so I am interested in minimizing the size of the data source that gets embedded in the HTML file.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips=[("series name","@legend")]

f = figure(tools=[hover])

data1 = ColumnDataSource({"x":[1,2,3], "y":[2,1,5], "legend":["series 1"]*3})
data2 = ColumnDataSource({"x":[1,2,3], "y":[1,7,2], "legend":["series 2"]*3})


f.line("x","y",source=data1, legend="series 1")
f.line("x","y",source=data2, legend="series 2")

show(f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do only works (efficient) if you associate a specific tooltip with a specific renderer. On Github there is an issue with the following comment, giving a small code snippet that does what you want: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3454#issuecomment-168238796

Comment: Thanks. That does the job. I do get the long list of hover tools in the enable drop down like shown in the GitHub link you shared.