# Bokeh: Box Annotation Hover

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

Is it possible to display information when hovering over a box annotation in Bokeh? My current work-around is to encode the information I want over the box annotation's region (duration, mean, var, etc. over time-series windows) in the tooltip displayed when hovering over individual points. But there is a fairly large amount of data, so that when zoomed out, it becomes very hard to hover over the individual points. I'd like to hover over the window itself (the box annotation) and have it display that information.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a solution to plot a "rect" or a "quad", with the same dimension as the BoxAnnotation (at least over Y axis), eventually with transparent color, then add hover.tooltips on this dummy rectangle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bokeh Plotting: Enable tooltips for only some glyphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435200/bokeh-plotting-enable-tooltips-for-only-some-glyphs)

Comment: @nic Seems a good trick but how can I make sure the top and bottom of the quad are always at the top and bottom of my figure, regardless of zooming?